# Can not solve this question

Tags: equation-solving

```
Solve[beta*x *((1 + (1 - m)*sigma*theta ((x^(-1/2) - 1)/((1 - theta)*x^(-1/2) + theta)))) - 
   S == 0, x]
```

Can someone please help me, I don't know why x is not solved . Thank you so so much!!

Comment: Use `Solve` with a capital `S`

Comment: Thank you zhk, I fixed the Solve, but still have odd long long results...

Comment: `LeafCount[Solve[...]]==35541` but `LeafCount[Simplify[Solve[...]]]==2054` so that makes the solution 17 times "simpler." `FullSimplify` might do even more, but it will be very very slow to finish that.

Answer (score 3):

The three solutions are the squares of the three [roots](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) of a third-order polynomial:

```
sol = {Root[S*(θ-1)-S*θ*#+β*(1-θ+θ*σ-m*θ*σ)*#^2+β*θ*(1-σ+m*σ)*#^3 &, 1]^2,
       Root[S*(θ-1)-S*θ*#+β*(1-θ+θ*σ-m*θ*σ)*#^2+β*θ*(1-σ+m*σ)*#^3 &, 2]^2,
       Root[S*(θ-1)-S*θ*#+β*(1-θ+θ*σ-m*θ*σ)*#^2+β*θ*(1-σ+m*σ)*#^3 &, 3]^2}
```

I don't think the solutions can be written any more succintly. To convert them into explicit formulas ([Cardano formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano's_method)), use the [`ToRadicals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html) command.